# How can I construct a class when the super class uses @Inject?

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> {

 final A a;

 @Inject
 AbstractClass(A a) {
   this.a = a;
 }
}

public class B extends AbstractClass<C> {

  final D d;

   @Inject
   B(D d) {
     super(); // this fails
     this.d = d;
   }

}
```

My `class B` extends `AbstractClass` and `AbstractClass` uses `@Inject` to inject `A` into it. In class `B` I cannot call `super()` because `AbstractClass` has an argument in the constructor. How can I handle the dependency injection of the superclass in the subclass to get `super()` working?

*How can I construct a class when the superclass uses `@Inject`?*

Comment: Sorry A was AbstractClass corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to accept an `A` as well:

```
@Inject
B(A a, D d) {
  super(a);
  this.d = d;
}
```

Then Guice should inject both the `A` and the `D`, and you just pass the `A` up to the superclass constructor. Just because a constructor is marked with `@Inject` doesn't mean it can *only* be invoked by Guice... In fact, I would actually remove the `@Inject` from `AbstractClass` - unless Guice has some magic I'm unaware of, it's not going to be able to inject that anyway.